# how to ajax call in simple rails application updating view page contents

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using [this](http://carmennorahgraydean.blogspot.in/2012/10/rails-328-ajax-super-basic-example.html?showComment=1372249413340#c7608656912024256783) tutorial , and have developed a simple application called ponies

this is what I have in view page ,

```
<% @ponies.each do |pony| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pony, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'delete_pony' %> </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

and in the controller :

```
def destroy
    @pony = Pony.find(params[:id])
    @pony.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ponies_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js   { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
```

clearly when i click on th link Destroy , script 'destroy.js.erb' file is executed

```
alert("in destroy.js.erb");

$('.delete_pony').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
    alert("in destroy.js.erb inside ajax success");
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
})
```

and succesfully deletes the pony object

but i create an extra link

```
<td><%= link_to 'hussi', pony , method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'preview_pony' %></td>
```

created preview method in controller

```
def preview
    @pony = Pony.find(params[:id])
    @hussi = @pony.name
    puts @hussi

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ponies_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js   { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
```

and also created file 'preview.js.erb'

```
alert("in preview.js.erb");

$('.preview_pony').bind('ajax:success', function()
{
alert("you did it , hussain");
})
```

but on clicking th elink preview , script written inside 'preview.js.erb' is never called , any explanation why ??

and also in first link
we use HTTP method :delete

now if i want simply to display some simeple method or to fade in/out some html element , what http method should i use

in the line :

```
<%= link_to 'hussi', pony , method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'preview_pony' %>
```

what object should i pass in place of 'pony'
what method should  i use in place of ':delete' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to define witch action to call in the controller:

```
<%= link_to 'hussi', {:action => "preview"}, method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'preview_pony' %>
```

and remember to add the route to the action in the `routes.rb` file, like

```
post 'ponies/preview'
```

Also, as a side note, I recommend you check out the [pry gem](https://github.com/pry/pry). You basically add

```
group :development do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-debugger'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
end
```

To your `Gemfile`, run `bundle install`, (probably restart your server), and you can call `binding.pry` in your code as a break point.

Comment: actually what i missed was tha in my prevew action i was taking the object passing a paramater id , but in case of preview link , there was no id being passed

Answer (score 0):

If U are creating the preview link through ajax. then that might break. Try using the `on('ajax:success',...`

Comment: @AbibullahRahamathulah : my problem is , the new js file , 'preview.js.erb' is never called after clicking on the link , i have given alert in the very first line

Comment: hmmm. can you check the browser console to see if there are any javascript errors If u don't see any errors at your rails console.